# how to redirect customer login after he register in opencart v 2.1?

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart v 2.1 my problem is when a new customer is registering, it is redirecting to account/success and after clicking on countinue button the customer is not redirecting to his account page instead redirecting to account/login please help me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is the function which is called when a customer registers on an OpenCart 2.X store.

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $customer_id = $this->model_account_customer->addCustomer($this->request->post);

        // Clear any previous login attempts for unregistered accounts.
        $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);

        $this->customer->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password']);
        unset($this->session->data['guest']);
        // Add to activity log
        $this->load->model('account/activity');
        $activity_data = array(
            'customer_id' => $customer_id,
            'name'        => $this->request->post['firstname'] . ' ' . $this->request->post['lastname']
        );
        $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('register', $activity_data);
        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/success'));
    }
```

The $this->customer->login() section auto logs them into their new account but they are being redirected to the login page again because it has not been successful.

You might have a setting in your OpenCart store which means customers need to be approved by admin, or need to verify their email address before they can checkout. You can find out by logging into your admin section and going to:

**Sales -> Customers -> Customer Groups -> Edit -> set "Approve new customers?" to No**

Comment: i cant find anything in Setting -> Setting -> Store -> Click Edit -> Go to the Option Tab so that i can change it?

Comment: Edited the answer, it's in the customer groups section.